using flutter Getx binding that is visible in visibility does not work even if the data has changed
i make a onboarding page using flutter and getx state management with binding,
when i try to set the visible the ui is not updating, so when im at the last page the skip and next icon is not gone and the button get started is not appears,also when im using Obx its say
      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
      

i tried to set the visible with a bool from onboarc controller like this
//button get started
Visibility(
  visible: controller.isLastPage == true,

and this
//skip and next button
Visibility(
  visible: controller.isLastPage == false,

and here is how i change in pageview.builder
onPageChanged: (index) {
  controller.isLastPage = index == 1;
},

while like here how i use in controller
bool isLastPage = false;

void nextPage() {
    currentPage.value++;
// i want to see the value of it
    print(isLastPage);
    if (currentPage.value >= 3) {
      // Jika sudah sampai halaman terakhir, pindah ke halaman selanjutnya
      Get.offAllNamed('/home');
    } else {
      pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
      isLastPage = true;
    }
  }

for refrence here is how i code for the onboarding
Expanded(
  child: PageView.builder(
    controller: controller.pageController,
    itemCount: pageContent.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      print(index);
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            pageContent[index]['image'],
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: 450,
            height: 600,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(
            pageContent[index]['header'],
            style: onboardingHeaderTextStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(
            pageContent[index]['subheader'],
            maxLines: 3,
            style: onboardingSubHeaderTextStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
        ],
      );
    },
    onPageChanged: (index) {
      controller.isLastPage = index == 1;
    },
  ),
),


its resolve ,so in this case i have to use Rxbool instead of bool,and after that i have to use obx in the column,and its work perfectly

Put your Visibility widget inside the Obx widget and try it out because whenever a value is changed Obx update the widget accordingly as it comes along with the Getx

So i wrap the 2 visibility in 1 obx right?i already tried that and its say improper using Getx

You must be updating a obs variable inside both the visibility widget after that it will not give any error for more clarification you can share the snippet of code where you are getting this error
